# Remove object from array with mongoose 5.12 ($pull not working)

Tags: arrays, object, mongoose, pull

I have a problem with mongoose 5.12.

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "60db70c9956a6c4d0645d447"
  },
  "articles": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "60db8764da322a23e787ca3d"
      },
      "type": "Déssert",
      "name": "dfd",
      "description": "",
      "price": 0,
      "tag": "",
      "picture": "noarticle.jpg"
    },
  ],
  "editor": 27,
}
```

My restaurant document contains articles (object array)

And I want to remove an article from it.

I'm using this:

```
const deletedArticle = await this.restaurantModel.findOneAndUpdate(
  { editor: userId },
  { $pull: { articles: articleId } },
  { multi: true, new: true, useFindAndModify: true },
);

// userId -> 27 and articleId --> "60db8764da322a23e787ca3d"
```

But nothing changes.

Is this an _id type problem? Or anything else?

(The $push option work)

Answer (score 0):

You did wrong in the line:

```
{ $pull: { articles: articleId } }
```

It should be:

```
{ $pull: { articles: { _id : articleId } } }
```

Or:

```
{ $pull: {"articles._id" : articleId } }
```

Comment: I also tried this way, but it doesn't work

Comment: But when i'm adding an id number and filter by it, it's works. But the problem is that auto-increment is not native in mongodb / mongoose.

Comment: On my opinion it's because when I add my _id to axios body, it translate it as a string. But I don't know how to type it back

Comment: Use const newId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(_id)